# How To Upload Multiple Image URL String Within Array

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, retrofit2

```
{
  "image_url": [
    {
      "image_url": "url1"
    },
    {
      "image_url": "url1"
    },
    {
      "image_url": "url1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I Want To Pass image_url As An Array To API With Multiple Image URL [String] How Can I Pass Like This Using Retrofit [Android - Kotlin]

```
val jsResult = JSONObject()
    
val jsArray = JSONArray()
    
for (i in 0 until imgOnlineList.size) {
    val jGroup = JSONObject()
    jGroup.put("imageURL", imgOnlineList[i])
    jsArray.put(jGroup)
}
jsResult.put("productCategory", jsArray)
    
Constant.logD(mTAG, "productCategoryOnlineList : ", jsResult.toString())
```

Comment: what have you tried till now?provide code

Comment: Also, tags go in the "tags" section, not in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Retrofit` with `Kotlin`, you don't need to write plain Json objects. You can set `Gson` converter in `Retrofit Builder`.

You can create two data classes

```
data class Image(val image_url: String)
data class ImageList(val image_url: List<Image>)
```

And then pass them to API call as `@Body` payload or however is required by API provider. e.g.,

```
@POST("{api_end_point}")
fun sendImages(@Body imageList: ImageList)
```

Comment: Thank You.. I Want To Add Data Dynamically To ImageList Data Class How Can I Add & Post It An A Body Param..

Comment: You can always create the custom `imageList` by dynamically adding `Image` objects to it. e.g., 
`val imageList = mutableListOf<Image>()
 imageList.add(Image("image_url"))`
And then pass the list to `sendImages` method.